# How to on/off compount button programmatically without affecting the onCheckedChanged() in onCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, oncheckedchanged

I use a `CompoundButton` in my app. I call a method named `newsLetterUpdate()` in the `onCheckedChange()` callback of `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`. I change the checked state of this `CompoundButton` programmatically, but the `onCheckedChange()` callback gets invoked. I want the `onCheckedChange()` to be triggered only if I switch the checked state on the `View`. 
Please suggest me a solution to change the state of compound button without the `onCheckedChange()` callback to be invoked.

Comment: take one flag and set false when you change state compound button programmatically and check this flag value in onCheckedChanged() base do your code.

Answer (score 4):

So as per your requirement I believe that you need to execute the code inside `onCheckedChange()` call back only if the user initiates the action. Right?

Then why are you using `onCheckedChange()`, you can use `onClickListener()` instead to achieve your goal.

Currently you have possibly written your code inside:

`compundbutton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(your_current_listener);`

Move that code from there to :

`compundbutton.setOnClickListener(your_new_listener);`

Then `onCheckedChange ()` listeners will not get invoked on setting checked state programiccally.

`compundbutton.setChecked(checked);`

Hope it may help you..! :)

Comment: I felt, unregister and register listener, this method is more efficient. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar issue. I had RadioGroup and when the user was opening the application I was setting the initial state and it was going in OnCheckedChangeListener and in my case was updating data in database which was very bad. I have solved it that in the OnCheckedChangedListener i was taking the button and setting in that method a OnClickListener:

```
viberPermissionView.getAppPermissions().setOnCheckedChangeListener(
        new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, 
            int checkedRadioButtonId) {
                final RadioButton checkedButton =     
            viberPermissionView.findViewById(checkedRadioButtonId);
                checkedButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startService(checkedButton, 
                          App.VIBER);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

With that when onCreate was called it was going in OnCheckedChangedListener but it wasn't going in OnClickListener. Only when the user will press the button it will go in OnClick and will execute in my case the startService. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1** : if you want on `checkChangeListener` should only be called while use interacts with the view then implemenet `onClickListener` put `newsLetterUpdate` method in that class

**Mehtod 2** : unregister the listener before you programmaticaly change the checkbox and register again when you are done

**Method 3** : use a boolean flag... set it when you change checkbox programmactically and set if false to when u are done... guard the code with that flag which you want to execute with user interaction only

Comment: It should work the newsLetterUpdate() method in checkChangeListener too. Then??

Comment: unregister the listener before you programmaticaly change the checkbox and register again when you are done .. for use a boolean flag... set it when you change checkbox programmactically and set if false to when u are done... guard the code with that flag which you dont want to execute with user interaction only

Answer (score 0):

**Method 4: Use a custom view**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class CustomSwitch extends Switch {


    private OnCheckedChangeListener mListener;

    public CustomSwitch(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
        // Do not call supper method
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        super.setChecked(checked);

        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onCheckedChanged(this, checked);
        }
    }

    public void setCheckedProgrammatically(boolean checked) {
        // You can call super method, it doesn't have a listener... he he :)
        super.setChecked(checked);
    }

}
```

Sample XML usage

```
<com.your.package.CustomSwitch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now the idea is to call the method **setCheckedProgrammatically** in code. **setChecked** gets called by Android when users changes the state of the compund button

Note that I'm using a switch, which extends the compund button, you can use basically the same code on any other (checkbox, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if onCheckedChange event is from user pressing the button, if you check isPressing value like this:

```
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object : CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

            override fun onCheckedChanged(switch: CompoundButton?, checked: Boolean) {
                if (switch == null) {
                    return
                }
                if (switch.isPressed) {
                    viewModel.onCheckedChanged(checked)
                }
            }

        })
```